# App Wrapper Fails to fix the framework "XojoFramework.framework"

Tags: mac-app-store, xojo

I have written a simple OS X application using Xojo, and I would like to submit it to the Mac App Store. I am using App Wrapper 3, as I have very little experience in this area. I am using the guide at http://forums.realsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?t=37030.

I created my certificates and everything, however when I attempt to wrap the application, it says:
Failed to fix the framework "XojoFramework.framework".

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you just ask the maker of the tool? Besides that, unless someone has had the same question and found a solution himself, no one can help you with the little information you give us to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: I agree, ask the tool vendor. They did just release an update so perhaps that is worth trying as well: https://forum.xojo.com/26183-app-wrapper-3-4-1-for-os-x-adds-el-capitan-xcode-7-compatibilit